# Update a column in table with the calculations mede with other column in same table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a situation where I need to update a row in a temp table with calculations made over some other columns data from same table.

I was able to do this for division and sum but not the complicated one like below
What I should do is

```
 UPDATE t
 SET    t.Value_Numeric = ((t.row9-((1-t.row28)*t.row26))/((1-t.row91))/(t.row33)-t.row85)
 FROM   #tempTable t
 where t.order = 93

 ** t.row9 means t.Value_Numeric  where t.order = 9
```

I was able to do a division like this

```
UPDATE #tempTable
 SET    #tempTable.Value_Numeric = reim.cmi
 FROM   #tempTable t
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT t1.Value_Numeric AS IPAllw ,
                            t2.Value_Numeric AS IPElig ,
                            t1.Value_Numeric / NULLIF(t2.Value_Numeric,0) AS cmi ,
                            t1.WorkingID
                     FROM   #tempTable t1
                            JOIN #tempTable t2 ON t1.WorkingID = t2.WorkingID
                                                  AND t1.order = 78
                                                  AND t2.order = 74
                     GROUP BY t1.WorkingID ,
                            t1.Value_Numeric ,
                            t2.Value_Numeric
                   ) reim ON reim.WorkingID = t.WorkingID
 WHERE  t.order = 79
```

help me to figure out the query to update the complex calculation.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS, which version? Table schemas? Indexes? Minimal, complete, reproducible example? Input example data? Expected result? Please don't expect that we know what you know. We only know what you write.

Comment: The code you have show is not valid PL/SQL (which you have tagged the question with). So what are you really using? I removed the `plsql` tag for now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Oracle in my answer based on the plsql tag given to the question.

**One possible solution would be to create a helper function as follows:**

```
create or replace function get_temptable_value(p_row in number) return temptable.value_numeric%type
is
  pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 
  v_val  temptable.value_numeric%type;
begin
  begin
    select value_numeric 
    into v_val
    from temptable 
    where row_order = p_row;
  exception 
    when no_data_found then
      v_val := null;
  end;

  return v_val;      
end;
```

The function returns null if the given row is not found, but it might be better to return 0 depending on your requirements. The autonomous pragma enables it to be called from an update statement (otherwise ORA-04091 is given):

```
update temptable t
SET    t.Value_Numeric = ((get_temptable_value(9)-((1-get_temptable_value(28))* get_temptable_value(26)))/((1- get_temptable_value(91)))/( get_temptable_value(33))- get_temptable_value(85))
where t.row_order = 93;
```

**2. Another solution would be the use of model cluase:**

```
create or replace view temptable_upd
as  
select *
from temptable t
model dimension by (row_order) 
      measures (value_numeric, value_numeric as new_value_numeric)
      rules (new_value_numeric[93] = ((value_numeric[9]-((1-value_numeric[28])* value_numeric[26]))/((1- value_numeric[91]))/( value_numeric[33])- value_numeric[85])
            );
```

In the rules section you can define any inter-row calculation.

Using the view, you can update the table:

```
update temptable t
set t.value_numeric = (select new_value_numeric from temptable_upd tupd where tupd.row_order = t.row_order) 
where t.row_order = 93;
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Create or replace procedure abc
>   Is
>   V_count number;
>   Begin
>   Select ur_calculations o/p into v_count from table ;Update 
>   Ur_table set col1 = v_count 
>   Where col2 =value;`

Commit;End;